# Is there a way to make this linq2sql more DRY?

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, dry

I would like to remove repetitions in this paragraph of code. Is it possible to write a function to cleanup any table nvarchar columns with a specified array of strings (or characters)? That query will be executed with ef core at the end.

I tried VS2022 refactoring tool to Extract Method, but it's extracting the whole Where(). I would like to "build" the Replaces chain. Is that possible?

```
var request = GetRequestValuesFromApi();

var query = _context.Persons.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Firstname))
{
    string firstname = request.Firstname.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("’", "").Replace("'", "");
    query = query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Collate(x.Firstname!, "binary_ai").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("’", "").Replace("'", "").Contains(firstname));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Lastname))
{
    string lastname = request.Lastname.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("’", "").Replace("'", "");
    query = query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Collate(x.Lastname!, "binary_ai").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("’", "").Replace("'", "").Contains(lastname));
}

// ...

var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: `linq2sql` is an obsolete library and it is not an `EF Core`, which is another library. Please correct your question details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), you can embed `Expression` variables in queries and have them expanded in place before the query is executed:

```
var query = _context.Persons.AsQueryable().AsExpandable();

Expression<Func<string,string>> FixNameEFn = (string name) => name.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("’", "").Replace("'", "");
var FixNameFn = FixNameEFn.Compile();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Firstname)) {
    string firstname = FixNameFn(request.Firstname);
    query = query.Where(x => FixNameEFn.Invoke(EF.Functions.Collate(x.Firstname!, "binary_ai")).Contains(firstname));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Lastname)) {
    string lastname = FixNameFn(request.Lastname);
    query = query.Where(x => FixNameEFn.Invoke(EF.Functions.Collate(x.Lastname!, "binary_ai")).Contains(lastname));
}
```

You can do this without LINQKit, but it would involve pushing the special operations up into a custom `Where` method (e.g., like `WhereNameContains`) which then builds or modifies an `Expression<Func<>>` and uses it in a regular `Where` call. But this would allow you to remove the `EF.Functions.Collate` repetition as well.